# Node.js serve as microservice service

Tags: node.js, microservices

I want to access my node.js server as service in microservice infrastructure. This means that if locally I can access node server services `/root-path-to-service`. But after deploying to infrastructure in AWS it is accessed as `/microservice-path/root-path-to-service` and `app.use('/root-path-to-service', ...)` does not work anymore. How can I configure to work in both cases?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Provide the path as an environment variable. Then read it from there in Node using:

```
process.env.ENV_VARIABLE_NAME
```

This is standard microservice practice.

Comment: I guess the original question is regarding URL, that matches to `app.use('/service-url-pattern')`. There might be several ways to work around, one of them could be using proxy to match `/microservice-path/` part and then your node app can remain same.

Comment: You may be right @HarryYoo, but let's not second guess. ;-)

Comment: This solution works as described. Thanks for hinting common practice, could not find it elsewhere. Thanks

Comment: Thanks for you comment @Ricardas. It's common practice not to store configuration information that is environment-specific together with the code. Environment variables are a common way to solve that problem.